# "Такой вопрос, похоже, уже был задан на stackoverflow на русском" при отметке вопроса тревогой

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация, вопросы, тревоги

Встретил на сайте [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1205117/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82), в комментариях к которому другой участник указал ссылку на [вопрос из англоязычного сообщества](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597167/css3-opacity-gradient). По этой ссылке, похоже, нашлось решение проблемы, так как под своим вопросом автор написал

> Благодарю

Я посчитал, отметить этот вопрос как дубликат, пользуясь ссылкой из комментариев будет правильно, ведь в описании тревоги сказано:

> Этот вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже есть ответ

Использовал ссылку из комментариев, но получил ошибку

> Такой вопрос, похоже, уже был задан на stackoverflow на русском

при отметке вопроса тревогой. Отметить не дает как быть?

Comment: Поставить дубликат со ссылкой на другой сайт нельзя

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Дубликат может быть только на ruSO. Если такого же вопроса на русском нет, то желательно перевести ответ с английского сайта.

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю, что сообщение об ошибке "Такой вопрос, похоже, уже был задан на stackoverflow на русском" в данном случае неверно. Если бы оно точно отражало суть, вопроса бы и не возникло. Оригинальная строка выглядит так:

> The duplicate question must exist on $siteName$

Предложил более подходящий вариант: https://ru.traducir.win/strings/7928

> Дубликат вопроса должен быть задан на сайте «$siteName$»

Comment: Упростил и утвердил